# How to show the city list in selectbox and the city list will be coming from database in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cities table in my database that contain the list of city and each city has their own id(Unique).

Now I want to show the list of city in a select box in my view page so that user can select the city from them.

I am using the below code in my controller:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from cities ORDER BY city_name");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['city_name'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<option selected="selected">No data</option>';
}
```

What code should I use in view to show the list if city in the select box?

Comment: You should render array with city names to view and use this code in view file.

Comment: So i should use $this -> render('viewname'); in controller

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a City model?

Than you can use the find('list') option in your controller:

```
$this->set('cities', $this->City->find('list',array('fields' => array('id','city_name'))));
```

Then in your view use this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('City');
```

More on the find list option:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

More on the form helper: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html